# EJB transactions behaving differently on Wildfly 8 between Windows and Linux deployments

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, ejb, atomic, wildfly-8

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with my web application hosted on Wildfly 8 when deployed on Linux OS compared to Windows Server. In my application, I rely on EJB transactions, which, by default, should be atomic. However, I noticed that transactions are behaving differently between the two environments.

On Windows Server, everything works as expected, and transactions remain intact. However, when I deploy the same application on a Linux OS, transactions seem to be cut off prematurely. After some investigation, I discovered that this behavior might be due to an automatic call to the `flush()` method before select statements.

Here are some additional details:

- Application server: Wildfly 8
- Operating systems: Windows Server for one deployment, Linux for another
- Database: PostgreSQL 9.3
- EJB transactions: Expected to be atomic
- Issue: Transactions are cut off on Linux deployments, possibly due to automatic `flush()` calls before select statements.

I've ensured that the configurations are consistent between the two environments. However, I'm struggling to understand why this difference in behavior occurs and how to address it.

Has anyone else encountered similar issues with EJB transactions on Wildfly 8.3, particularly between different operating systems? Are there any specific configurations or settings I should be aware of when deploying on Linux to ensure transactional integrity?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I suspected the operating system might be playing a role. However, further investigation revealed the culprit was the JTA (Java Transaction API) property within my data source configuration on Wildfly 8.

**Understanding the JTA Property:**

By default, the JTA property is set to true in Wildfly, enabling container-managed transactions. This ensures the application server handles transaction lifecycles (begin, commit, rollback). However, if this property was inadvertently set to false, EJB transactions wouldn't be managed by Wildfly, leading to unexpected behavior.

verify the JTA property in your DataSource configuration on Wildfly 8. Ensure it's explicitly set to true or left at its default value (which is also true). This guarantees container-managed transactions and the expected atomic behavior of your EJB transactions.